# Xcode cannot access to my iTunes Connect account

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

The newest version of Xcode cannot access to my developer account. I can log in using itunesconnect.apple.com without any problems. I have logged in to Xcode in Preferences but when I upload my app archive I have an error:

[image]

I'm trying to use Application Loader, but I have another error when I'm trying to log in:

[image]

Can you help me? Maybe you have the same problem? Thank you for your attention, sorry for my English)

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: Yes. Adding 2nd user to iTunes Connect team and logging to Xcode with both accounts works for me